# In proving trace(AB) = trace (BA), I not only swapped summands but also the order of summation - is this ok to do?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, trace

In proving this for a Linear Algebra course, I'm guessing we are allowed to assume that the vector spaces are finite-dimensional, so a double summation, summing up to n, does not pose a problem, when swapping the order (swapping the summands is trivial, as multiplication is commutative.)

Or, do I need to justify the step of switching the order of summation?

Thanks,

Comment: You mean you did something like $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}\sum_{m=1}^{M} a_{m,n} = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{m,n}$? Yes, that's completely legitimate with finite sums: you can sum the terms in any order you like. It's even legitimate for infinite sums if the terms are all positive, or if the convergence is absolute.

Comment: Yeah! that seems correct for me.

Comment: As bungo says, this is legit. What do you mean by "assume the spaces are finite dimensional"? Of course we can do that, otherwise the question does not make any sense.

Comment: Ok got it - thanks so much for the confirmation @Bungo.  I think when letting n go to infinity, this becomes something called Tonelli's theorem, which requires positive summands.  But I'm glad I got the finite case for sure now...

Comment: Hi @AmitaiYuval -- hmm...is there no trace to be computed for an infinitely large matrix?  Just out of curiosity...say, in studying functional analysis?   Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames: That's exactly right, for infinite sums (or integrals), it's Tonelli's or Fubini's theorem.

Comment: There is a notion of trace for operators in infinite dimensions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class

Comment: Ok, thanks again @Bungo :-)

Comment: @LebronJames, if you have found the answer, please consider posting it as an answer and pushing it out of "unanswered" queue!